# How to humanize measurement queries in Django

Tags: django, humanize

I have a distance query in Django and prints a distance with several decimal points. It displays distance in a measurement format as *1023.40258027906 m* .I want to make this human readable. I tried using Decimal but this failed as it does not apply to measurement objects. Measurement objects are distance objects with labels like km, m, cm. By humanize, I mean not more than 2 or 3 decimal digits. These are import from

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
```

Here is the Queryset used to generate the distance measurements.
Queryset:

```
queryset = Apartment.objects.filter(geom__distance_lte=(user_location, D(km=2))).annotate(distance=Distance('geom', user_location))


 <style type="text/css">
        ul{
            list-style-type: circle;
            margin:0px;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }
    </style>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body><strong>Nearby Apartments</strong>
        {% if apartments %}
        <ul>
        {% for apartment in apartments %}
            <li>
            {{ apartment.apt_id }}: {{apartment.distance}}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div> 
    </body>
```

Comment: You never mention what _exactly_ "Measurement objects" are (perhaps from `django.contrib.gis.measure`?) and what exactly you mean by humanize, please specify that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round the value to a specific precision you can use the [`floatformat` template filter [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) to do this.

Since the distance is a `Distance` object from `django.contrib.gis.measure` you can get the distance in your preferred format by  writing `distance.<format_name>` e.g. `distance.m` and then you can use `floatformat` on that:

```
<!-- round to 3 decimal places -->
{{ apartment.distance.m|floatformat:3 }} m
```

There are more ways to configure the output of this filter which are shown in the documentation linked above.